# CSS - bevel square and turn

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I need help edit the CSS square as shown below. Please advice about how to combine transform skew and rotate?

**FROM:**

[image]

**TO:**

[image]

my atempt:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s62ku64h/)

```
.square {
  background: #fff;
  border:2px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin:100px;
  transform:  skewX(-30deg) rotate(45deg);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: oki, I tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/s62ku64h/

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider what you need to do :

- **Rotate (Z-axis)** - Clearly your square is rotated at a 45° angle, so we will need to handle this. This is the easiest angle to notice.
- **Rotate (X-axis)** - It's difficult to discern the exact angle that you need to rotate backwards, so you may need to [play with this](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/#playground) to get the angle just right.

**Applying the Transforms**

With that being said, you can use the `transform` property along with the appropriate browser implementations of it together to get something like this :

```
.special-rotate {
    -ms-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

This will give you something that looks like the following example, which should get you to a point that you can determine exactly the values that you are looking for :

[image]

```css
#square {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id='square'></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but unfortunately length parties after the skew has only 140px instead of 200px .. :(

Comment: You can also look at performing skews on just specific axies (i.e. `skewX(...)`, `skewZ(...)`, etc.). I'd highly recommend playing around with the "playground" link I provided earlier and you may also want to check out [this more in-depth post on using CSS transforms](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/css-transforms/).